# Styling individual Ruby link tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this is what I have written in html:

```
<a href="/" style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231);">Home</a>
```

and I was wondering how I would convert that into Ruby format, this is what I have:

```
<%= link_to "Home", style: border-right: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231);, root_path %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the syntax for `link_to` tag

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil)
```

You can refer to `rails docs` for tag syntax

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path, {:style=>'border-right: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231)'} %>
```